# CodeMirror insert items into HTML Editor JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, editor, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror (see here -->) [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/2/). Specifically, I'm using the "HTML Editor With Preview" module.

I've been testing it in a fiddle: -------> http://jsfiddle.net/Vu33n/6/

I got the editor to work, however I'm trying to make it so that when a user selects an HTML tag from the drop-down menu - that code will insert into the editor WHERE THE CURSOR POSITION IS.

I can get the code to insert into the editor - but it erases everything in the editor before it inserts. I cannot get it to insert code where the cursor is and leave everything else alone.

The CodeMirror syntax I'm using is:

```
editor.setValue($(this).val());
```

If you are curious, the CodeMirror User Manual is [here](http://codemirror.net/2/doc/manual.html). Thats where i found 'setValue'

Answer (score 3):

I apologize. I finally found the answer here --> [replaceSelection](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codemirror/uynWZN3wr0M)

So the code needs to read:

```
editor.replaceSelection($(this).val());
```

Sorry for the post - but maybe this will help someone else out in the future.

Comment: don't apologize, this is beneficial for everyone. well done finding the answer yourself!

Answer (score 0):

The change you suggested:

```
editor.replaceSelection($(this).val());
```

works fine in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vu33n/181/
Go ahead and accept your own answer.